# How to view all Approvals in an organisation?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft365

For audit purposes, we would like to be able to see all `Approvals` within an organisation.

Individual users can go to:

`Teams application` > `Approvals` (in navigation menu)

And it displays a list of their `Received` and `Sent` approvals.

How can an admin view ALL `Approvals` that have taken place in an organisation?

(if it makes any difference, the Approvals are created from a Power Automate flow using [Approval actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/get-started-approvals))

Comment: I actually don't believe it's possible.  Happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: If that is the case (which would surprise and sadden me), do you think the best 'workaround' would be writing to a Microsoft List created for this purpose (from a Power Automate flow) when an Approval was commenced, approved or rejected?  (thinking out loud, that could end up being expensive money-wise).  I was planning on trying to convince users in an organisation that Approvals is a great way to keep track of approvals for audit purposes, but perhaps that is not the case.

Comment: Trust me, it would surprise me too but everything I've seen, I can't see anything out of the box.  The approval system is great but yeah, it's a bit crap if as an admin, you can't see all of the outstanding approvals.  If you could route **ALL** approvals through a flow that does the work to log it to a list, etc. then yes, you could make that work but you'd have to catch all of those where that wasn't happening.  If you're taking the citizen approach and users can administer their own approval flows then you'll have to keep on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the Approval data gets stored in Dataverse.

I would suggest to have a look at the Approval (msdyn_flow_approval), Approval Request (msdyn_flow_approvalrequest) & Approval Response (msdyn_flow_approvalresponse) tables in Dataverse for this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer, I did some more googling and this video seems to confirm Approvals data is indeed stored in the Dataverse:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT_kL43gJH0 .  Do you know if there is a URL to browse through data in the Dataverse?  And also, how long Approvals data is saved for?   My instance of Power Apps doesn't seem to have the same 'Dataverse' links that are shown in the linked video, so I can't find it.  **Edit:**  Actually, it is at https://make.powerapps.com/ - the relevant navigation link there is `Tables` (there is no `Dataverse` link in the menu for me).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All these entities/tables and the related records/rows should be listed in the Tables section of your Default environment (make sure you select the correct environment in the right top corner) which you can access via either https://make.powerapps.com or https://make.powerautomate.com